# Getting Hello World in AIR to install

Tags: air

I have an AIR application that is the following:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

It runs on my local machine:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AIR\HelloWorldDestination.air

And it runs if I choose "preview in Adobe AIR" in Dreamweaver.

But I can't get it to download and install from [my website](http://www.PhillipSenn.com/AIR).
Here is the application.xml that Dreamweaver created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0">
    <filename>HelloWorldFileName</filename>
    <copyright>Hello World Copyright</copyright>
    <description>Hello World Description</description>
    <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
    <name>HelloWorldAppName</name>
    <id>com.PhillipSenn.HelloWorldID</id>
  <version>1</version>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>HelloWorld.htm</content>
    <height>600</height>
    <width>800</width>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
  </initialWindow>
</application>
```

It's giving me an error 2032.
I have uploaded these files as well:

- AC_RunActiveContent.js
- badge.swf
- HelloWorldDestination.air

Here's my line of code in Index.htm:

```
'flashvars','appname=HelloWorldAppName&appurl=http://www.PhillipSenn.com/AIR/HelloWorldDestination.air&airversion=2.0&imageurl=css/Install.gif',
```

When I create the AIR file, Dreamweaver gives me the following warning:

> In order to install this application
>   on your machine, you need the  Adobe
>   AIR runtime that can be downloaded
>   from: http://www.adobe.com/go/air

Comment: http://www.swatchdog.com/AIR/HelloWorldDestination.air cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Alin!  I've since changed the reference to PhillipSenn.com/AIR/HelloWorldDestination.air.  (SwatchDog.com and PhillipSenn.com go to the same IP address).  The file is really is up there.  I've added a link to the Index.htm page so that you can see that HelloWorldDestination.air really is up there.

Comment: No it isn't :). You just save a HTML file with an .air extension. Open the file with a text editor to see.

Comment: If I try to open http://www.PhillipSenn.com/AIR/HelloWorldDestination.air in WordPad, it says "File not found".  But it really is up there.  I can right-click on the link at http://www.PhillipSenn.com/AIR/Index.htm and it will download.

Comment: Try both left-clicking http://www.PhillipSenn.com/AIR/HelloWorldDestination.air and right-clicking on the same link here in this comment.

Comment: As I said: what I'm saving is a HTML page, **nothing more**. The only thing is that I save it with an air extension. That HTML file is the output of your server saying that the file was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application to be installed cannot be found at http://www.phillipsenn.com/AIR/HelloWorldDestination.air

Comment: By adding the correct mime type, my program began working.  Thanks Alin!